# Optimal buffer size for write(2)

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, filesystems

Let's say I want to write a 1 GB of data to the file on, say `ext3` Linux filesystem using `write(2)` syscall and this happens in a very **busy environment** (many similar I/Os concurently). What is the optimal buffer size in the interval, say, `[4 kB, 4 MB]` to do that when

1. not using `O_DIRECT` open flag, or
2. using `O_DIRECT`?

Please, no "check it yourself" answers -- I'd like to get some answer from "filesystems" guys.

Comment: Try to benchmark yourself. I believe the size don't matter much, at least in the `[16kb, 1MB]` range.... And I don't think it is very sensitive to the size... (the real bottleneck is the disk hardware)

Comment: You can get the block-size of a file system by calling `stat` on a file (e.g. `stat(".")`). I would think the result would be an good buffer size.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Try reading a few bytes vs a few kilobytes per call. The performance improvement when reading large blocks is huge. But then again, in the range you gave you are probably right.

Comment: Yes, the range I gave was significant. I do know that 4kb is often a page size and a chunk size on filesystems.

Comment: If you can align to a block size and allocate that much then it would be a good number to choose. Unfortunately, aligned memory allocation is a bit hit and miss. MSVC gives you a specific function (`_aligned_malloc`), there is another one called `memalign` which is sometimes implemented.

Comment: POSIX has `posix_memalign`  and linux also has `valloc` and `memalign` to allocate aligned memory.

Comment: Isn't `BUFSIZ` what you need?

Comment: Please, discussion about aligned memory is a little bit orthogonal to the question, everything is assumed to be aligned properly.

Comment: Of course, I was assuming a nice size, e.g. a power of 2. I would imagine that reading 8099 bytes sized blocks don't make any sense.

Comment: @Basile: Exactly, everything is of `2^k` size, aligned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As discussed in comments, I believe the exact size don't matter that much, assuming it is :

- a small multiple of the file system size (see comment by  Joachim Pileborg suggesting `stat(".")` etc.)
- a power of two (because computers and kernels like them)
- not too big (e.g. fitting in some cache inside your processor, e.g. L2 cache)
- aligned in memory (e.g. to a page size using `posix_memalign`).

So a power of two between 16kbytes and a few megabytes should probably fit. Most of the time is spent on reading the disk. Filesystem and disk benchmarks are quite flat in that range.

4Kbytes seems to often be the page size and the disk chunk size.

Of course, you can tune things, even tune, when making the file system with `mke2fs`, the file system block size.

And I'll bet that the optimal is really dependent upon your hardware (SSD, hard disks?) and your system (and its load).

Answer (score 11):

The answer is in my experience much more dependent on the underlying devices and hardware rather than the filesystem itself -- that is buffer caches on the device, and the capabilities of the device to write in small blocks etc -- however you should never write in smaller sizes than your file system block size (`stat(.)` -- likely to be about **4kb**) -- similarly you should not really go beyond the L2/L3 cache size of the CPU which in many cases can be as low as **512kb**.

Given that SSD devices and similar *like* the 64kb as the unit of operations, then I would suggest that a buffer size of **64kb-128kb** being the most optimal -- which also correspond with my empirical experience as having the highest throughput.

Answer (score 0):

Including stdio.h should define BUFSIZ as the optimal size for the system.  This is by no means guaranteed, but it is the right value to use if you do not have the ability to do extensive benchmarks, and it is a good starting point for such benchmarks.

Comment: I would believe that the `BUFSIZ` defined in `<stdio.h>` is related to the `FILE` abstraction provided there. The original poster is talking about `write(2)` syscalls on Linux, without the `FILE` abstraction. I don't understand why the `BUFSIZ` would be related to that.

Comment: AFAIK, BUFSIZ is the size of the buffer passed to setvbuf.  The FILE abstraction is designed to do efficient IO, and the buffer size is generally chosen with that in mind.

Comment: Agreed, but why should the size of the `setvbuf`-ed size be the same as the `write` size?

Comment: Because the buffer size is chosen in an effort to maximize the efficiency of the buffering.

Comment: I don't think `BUFSIZ`is changing a lot, for binary compatibility reasons. I'll guess `BUFSIZ` has been chosen more than ten years ago, on systems with different constraints and optimum than our current machines.