# minimum write size with O_DIRECT

Tags: c, linux

I am writing a custom database engine for Linux 2.6.X kernels in C and I need to know what is the minimum write size of a write() system call for a file opened with O_DIRECT flag? In the docs it says that since linux 2.6 kernel versions you can use 512 byte block. But, what if my hard disk uses 8K blocks? Will it return EINVAL error on write in this case? I heard disks with 512 byte sector are becoming obsolete and the new disks use 8K sector, so I need to be sure my app doesn't crash when the user tries it on such disk.
In case of it is possible to use 512 byte writes on a disk with 8k sectors, what happens when I write , say  2 blocks of 512 bytes , does the linux kernel reads the 8k sector from disk, replaces the 1k block I told it to write and then writes back to disk the 8k sector? This would be real slow!

Also, there is another question I have regarding this issue, does the minimum write size varies if I use raw device or a ext3 filesystem when opening file?

Comment: As far as I know there is no minimum size. You can write one byte at a time if you want to, although the performance will be really bad in that case. Optimal write are probably multiples of the disk block size.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8803741/841108 is an answer to a very related question. I suggest writing 64k bytes. And perhaps make that configurable, because the best size depends upon the system and hardware.

Comment: "As far as I know there is no minimum size" <-- this is not correct. I  just coded a write routine and it returns EINVAL because the write size is not a multiple of 512 bytes

Comment: Basile, your answer to the question you posted in the link is not correct either. posix_memalign has nothing to do with disk blocks. neither page size of the processor has anything to do with it. Soren's answer is more correct, but it is still not clear what happens if I write 512 bytes on a disk with 4k or 8k physical sectors. I guess I will have to buy the hardware and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no general way to know the constraints of O_DIRECT. This manual page seems to kill any hope:

http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/open.2.html

Also, I am quite sure that the block size may change depending on the underlaying filesystem

Answer (score -1):

Slightly OT,  "I heard disks with 512 byte sector are becoming obsolete and the new disks use 8K sector," - are there any 8K sectors disks out there. I believe the newer disks use 4K sector sizes also known as advanced format disks. 8K sectors disks are being thought about for the future but i doubt if any manufacturer has come out with them yet

Regarding your query, i think its the sector size of disk. So if you have a 4K disk, you need to issue a read/write with size 4K. In the case of O_DIRECT the read/write is passed directly to the disk and a disk can read/write with granularity == sector size (logical block size reported by the disk)