# what's the proper buffer size for 'write' function?

Tags: c, linux, file, io

I am using the low-level I/O function 'write' to write some data to disk in my code (C language on Linux). First, I accumulate the data in a memory buffer, and then I use 'write' to write the data to disk when the buffer is full. So what's the best buffer size for 'write'? According to my tests it isn't the bigger the faster, so I am here to look for the answer.

Comment: +1 for asking a good question... I always wanted to know the right size for write function....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Optimal buffer size for write(2)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803515/optimal-buffer-size-for-write2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is probably some advantage in doing writes which are multiples of the filesystem block size, especially if you are updating a file in place. If you write less than a partial block to a file, the OS has to read the old block, combine in the new contents and then write it out. This doesn't necessarily happen if you rapidly write small pieces in sequence because the updates will be done on buffers in memory which are flushed later. Still, once in a while you could be triggering some inefficiency if you are not filling a block (and a properly aligned one: multiple of block size at an offset which is a multiple of the block size) with each write operation.

This issue of transfer size does not necessarily go away with mmap. If you map a file, and then `memcpy` some data into the map, you are making a page dirty. That page has to be flushed at some later time: it is indeterminate when. If you make another `memcpy` which touches the same page, that page could be clean now and you're making it dirty again. So it gets written twice. Page-aligned copies of multiples-of a page size will be the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want it to be a multiple of the CPU page size, in order to use memory as efficiently as possible.

But ideally you want to use mmap instead, so that you never have to deal with buffers yourself.

Comment: So if you want to write out 3GB of data, it's okay to make a 3GB mmap? Haha.  You could make a smaller mmap and then remap it as you advance through the file, which is more complicated. As for no buffers: well, what is the mmap? It's a region of memory with a base pointer, and some current pointer which tells you where to memcpy the next piece. And what's the ideal size for those memcpy operations? If you copy 300 bytes here, 300 bytes there, you could trigger sub-optimal flushes. I.e. the CPU could catch you making the same page dirty twice and flush it twice.

Comment: what if the data to be processed is far more bigger than RAM?

Comment: If you have more than 3Gb of RAM and wants to write 3Gb of data, it is definitely ok to `mmap` all of it. You could use `madvise` to fine-tune.

Comment: Also, what if you don't know how large the file will be in advance? Do you make a worst-case mapping and let it extend the file, or make additonal mmap calls to extend it? If you acquire a map in multiple steps, what if something is in the way? 200 megs is fine at a certain address now, but later fails to extend to 300 megs because `malloc` put something in the way. If mmap was a good idea in place of buffered stream I/O, maybe glibc would implement `FILE *` streams that way.

Comment: mmap may not care about RAM, but it cares about virtual space. And strict overcommit accounting cares about virtual space in relation to RAM, by the way!

Comment: Basically rampant usage mmap is for cowboys who just learned about mmap. Threads suffer from this! "I just took concurrent programming 317 and now everythiing I write for the next 6 months will launch 400 threads." :)

Comment: Glibc may use `mmap` e.g. when `fopen`-ing with mode containing `m`

Comment: I.e. you have to ask glibc for it; what is the reason for that?

Comment: Also, what is the good memcpy size if you mmap? The system could catch you making the same page dirty twice in a row resulting in redundant writes. (mmap does not entirely resolve the question of transfer unit size and alignment! merely it changes `lseek`-s/`write`-s to `memcpy`-s.)

Answer (score 3):

You could use `BUFSIZ` defined in `<stdio.h>`

Otherwise, use a small multiple of the page size `sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)` (e.g. twice that value). Most Linux systems have 4Kbytes pages (which is often the same as or a small multiple of the filesystem block size).

As other replied, using the [mmap(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) system call could help. GNU systems (e.g. Linux) have an extension: the second mode string of [fopen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen) may contain the latter `m` and when that happens, the GNU libc try to `mmap`.

If you deal with data nearly as large as your RAM (or half of it), you might want to also use [madvise(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/madvise) to fine-tune performance of `mmap`.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8803741/841108) to a question quite similar to yours. (You could use 64Kbytes as a reasonable buffer size).

Answer (score 2):

The "best" size depends a great deal on the underlying file system.

The `stat` and `fstat` calls fill in a data structure, `struct stat`, that includes the following field:

```
blksize_t st_blksize; /* blocksize for file system I/O */
```

The OS is responsible for filling this field with a "good size" for write() blocks.  However, it's also important to call write() with memory that is "well aligned" (e.g., the result of `malloc` calls).  The easiest way to get this to happen is to use the provided `<stdio.h>` stream interface (with `FILE *` objects).

Using `mmap`, as in other answers here, can also be very fast for many cases.  Note that it's not well suited to some kinds of streams (e.g., sockets and pipes) though.

Comment: you mean fwrite is generally faster than write with a proper buffer size?

Comment: Not necessarily "faster than", but it will do fast block copies in user-space as needed.  Moreover, if you need to write a bunch of different short strings from various locations, it will gather them all together and pass one appropriately-sized block to the kernel, in one system call.  (You can achieve a similar effect with `writev` in some cases but it's usually more work than it's worth—and even then the kernel tends to have to do the same memory copies.)

Comment: This value is intended to be exactly that, but it has turned out that if I use this value, it is still slower if e.g. copying data from A to B, because I have to make more syscalls this way.

Comment: If the value returned in `st_blksize` is not actually optimal, the kernel is failing to hold up its end of the bargain. :-)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the amount of RAM, VM, etc. as well as the amount of data being written. The more general answer is to benchmark what buffer works best for the load you're dealing with, and use what works the best.

Comment: what's a good way to calculate the proper amount given all of this

Comment: Iterate through the different settings for buffer sizes and benchmark it?

Comment: that works i guess i was wondering if there was some sort of formula based off of ram ,vm exc