# How to reduce overhead in my C program?

Tags: c, linux, optimization

I am using C on linux, and my program is both of high CPU-density an I/O-density. Using time command shows that my program having much overhead:

```
real    1m4.639s
user    0m53.929s
sys         0m9.747s
```

Is that possible to find out what costs 'sys    0m9.747s' and reduce it?

=================================================

Excuse me if this question isn't easy to answer without the code, but my code is too long to be posted here. So any tips or clues will also do. Thank you

Comment: it's too long to post. Actually I am doing a simple inverted indexing

Comment: If you eliminate *all* the system time, you've only speeded your program up by 16%.  You will probably get more bang for your buck concentrating on the 53 seconds of user time; if you make a 20% reduction in that time, you've outperformed what you'd achieve by the impossible 100% reduction in system time.

Comment: relevant: [Amdahl's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law)

Comment: *Excuse me if this question isn't easy to answer without the code* - Not difficult, completely impossible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The system CPU time is the time spent in the kernel for your process, doing system calls. You could use `strace` to find out which system calls your process is doing.

Maybe you have many many small [read](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) system calls (or [write](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write) ones). You might lower their number by increasing your buffers size (so each `read` and `write` would transmit more bytes). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9662472/841108) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8803741/841108) answers to relevant questions.

You could also use [mmap](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) to project files into (virtual) memory; this could be a better way for some kind of disk I/O.

But I won't focus specifically on system time. It seems to eat only 15% of the CPU time which is a reasonable ratio.

I would suggest to profile your program (using `gprof` or `oprofile`) and to find where are the bottlenecks.

Comment: +1: Profile! Until you've done that, so you know where your program spends its time, you are likely to try to optimize the wrong things.

Comment: yes, there're many read and write callings, I am gonna do a test

Answer (score 3):

That is an extremely open-ended question, and there is no specific right answer given how broad the question is without more information. That said, I would recommend you use something like `valgrind` to profile your application, figure out what specific functions in your code are taking the most time, and work on optimizing them.

With that out of the way, you should really concentrate on the time spent in user land. With 53 secs vs 9 secs of system time, you'll probably be able to optimize a heck of a lot more there. Your optimization time would be better used there.