# Writing huge txt files without overloading RAM

Tags: c++, file-io

I need to write the results of a process in a txt file. The process is very long and the amount of data to be written is huge (~150Gb). The program works fine, but the problem is that the RAM gets overloaded and, at a certain point, it just stops.

The program is simple:

```
ostream f;
f.open(filePath);
for(int k=0; k<nDataset; k++){
    //treat element of dataset
    f << result;
}
f.close();
```

Is there a way of writing this file without overloading the memory?

Comment: f >> result;  
if (k%10000 ==0)   f.flush();

Comment: What do you mean "ram gets overloaded"?  Thrashing?  Process using lots more memory that the machine has memory?

Comment: Your question says you are having problems with *writing* a *text* file, but your code shows *reading* a *compressed* file.  -1 for a question that is "unclear or not useful"

Comment: @BenVoigt It was obviously a typo. The original program is correct. But thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @DanielX2010: It obviously was a mistake, but it wasn't obvious what the correct meaning was.  Copying/pasting the wrong part of the program "because it's very late", vs breaking into the debugger when the program gets slow, seeing file I/O code, and mistakenly thinking it's the file output code "because it's very late" both seem equally plausible to me.

Comment: @BenVoigt The most important part in the question was the text (and I mentioned that the program worked fine), but your argument is reasonable. Thanks anyway. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should flush output periodically.

For example:

```
if (k%10000 == 0) f.flush();
```

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: I disagree with these comments. This is clearly not only an answer but *the* answer, if, as it appears, the `igzstream` never flushes itself. +1

Comment: @EJP: Why would an `igzstream` need to be flushed?  (Hint: *i* is for *input*, and he's extracting data from it)

Comment: @BenVoigt The answer may be incorrect but it's still an answer. Your question should be addressed to Jim.

Comment: @EJP: Jim will get notified of my comment anyway, because it's attached to his answer.

Comment: The code fragment did not really match the problem as written.  Perhaps 'result' needs to be flushed.

Comment: @EJP @Jim Thanks for you comments. There are 2 "typos" (copied+pasted wrong part of code) in the question I've written (`ogzstream` instead of `ostream` and `>>` instead of `<<`). Flushing seems to be the answer to the problem. I'll check if it works when I get home tonight and then I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, for some reason I caught some flak for this one... :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to suggest something like this

```
ogzstream f;
f.open(filePath);
string s("");
for(int k=0; k<nDataset; k++){
    //treat element of dataset

    s.append(result);

    if (s.length() == OPTIMUM_BUFFER_SIZE) {
        f << s;
        f.flush();
        s.clear();
    }

}

f << s;
f.flush();
f.close();
```

Basically, you construct the stream in memory rather than redirecting to the stream so you don't have to worry about when the stream gets flushed. And when you are redirecting you ensure it's flushed to the actual file. Some ideas for the `OPTIMUM_BUFFER_SIZE` can be found from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9662425/whats-the-proper-buffer-size-for-write-function) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540725/optimal-buffer-size).

I'm not exactly sure whether string or vector is the best option for the buffer. Will do some research myself and update the answer or you can refer to *Effective STL* by Scott Meyers.

Comment: If the `igzstream` really is using up memory, writing to a string or a vector is redundant. The only part of this that solves the problem or even changes anything is the `flush()`.

Comment: @EJP: Except that `flush()` is a member of `ostream`, not `istream`.

Comment: @BenVoigt Perhaps you misunderstood what I meant. What this does is concatenate data into a string and write it to a file when the size is optimum to be written (e.g., same as I/O buffer size). No where in the answer is it suggested that concatenated data are *overwritten* with data from a file. Don't understand why you downvoted?

Comment: @BenVoigt Apologies... I naively copied the question's code to the answer. Question says the requirement is to *write* to a file but the code is *reading* from a file. Probably mistyped redirection operators. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @ubi: I tend to trust the code more than the explanation... but you might be right.  I've removed my downvote.

Answer (score 1):

If that truly is the code where your program gets stuck, then your explanation of the problem is  wrong.

- There's no text file.  Your `igzstream` is not dealing with text, but a `gzip` archive.
- There's no data being written.  The code you show *reads* from the stream.
- I don't know what your program does with *result*, because you didn't show that.  But if it accumulates results into a collection in memory, that will grow.  You'll need to find a way to process all your data without loading all of it into RAM at the same time.
- Your memory usage could be from the decompressor.  For some compression algorithms, an entire block has to be stored in memory.  In such cases it's best to break the file into blocks and compress each separately (possibly pre-initializing a dictionary with the results of the previous block).  I don't think that *gzip* is such an algorithm, however.  You may need to find a library that supports streaming.

Comment: Actually my code is huge and there was no need to put the entire code here. My code is working "just fine": it computes the result as I nedd and it writes it to the txt file. The thing is that the memory consumption explodes when the txt file gets too big. It was evry late and I mistyped (copied+pasted wrong part of code) 2 things in the question (`ogzstream` instead of `ostream` and `>>` instead of `<<`). Thanks for pointing out the erros, but you could be more humble and less aggressive next time.

Comment: @DanielX2010: It's not usually a good idea to tell the experts trying to help you to be more humble.  More tactful/less aggressive; ok I'll give you that.  Anyway, you posted a very ambiguous question, which is enough to make many experts just move along and find a better written one.  I saw that there were answers addressing the description and assuming the code was flawed, I chose to offer an answer which would be helpful if the code were correct and the description flawed.

Comment: +1 for a more restrained post.  Ambiguous information for these problems is par for the course here, so some restraint is needed.  I was wrong to suggest flush() for a file read, but the problem sounded like a flush issue and probably is.  (If you edit it again, I will remove my downvote.)