# Optimal way of storing stream content on disk using Python

Tags: python, file, memory, stream

I'd like to stream data directly to disk.

One way of doing that is simply to read data and write to file, but I also want to minimalize RAM usage.

```
with open("dummy.source", "br") as out, open("dummy.copy", "bw") as in_:
    in_.write(out.read())  # this causes reading the whole stream into memory
```

I've figured out some manual way of doing that:

```
with open("dummy.source", "br") as out, open("dummy.copy", "bw") as in_:
    while b := out.read(BUFFER_SIZE):
        in_.write(b)
```

Do I really have to manually load stream part by part?
If so, how can I determine optimal value of `BUFFER_SIZE`?

Comment: I haven't been able to find a way to directly connect the streams, so I think the loop is the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the optimal value of buffer size is most likely the size of the buffer already reserved by python which is `8192` bytes on most systems, but any value below that is fine as the IO will be buffered by python anyway.

you can change that using the `buffering` argument of `open` but `8192` is the optimal size on a lot of systems.

you can actually grab it from the current python interpreter by using

```py
from io import DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE
```

this is in case it is changed in the future or for a given python interpreter.

Comment: I've tried several values and values greater than 8192 provided slightly better performance, but it was limited by size of input buffer over which I won't have control in production example. `io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE` looks like a great value, thanks.

Comment: Here's some related SA question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540725/optimal-buffer-size-for-read-process-write